# UIButton does not respond to removeFromSuperView when returning to VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UIButton that I implement programmatically as it is only required when I rotate the device.

The button needs to disappear when I go rotate and appear when I go landscape.

As long as I stay in the same ViewController I have no issues. I can rotate the device in anyway and the button appears and disappears as expected.
The app is a TabController based app and when I go to another tab the same behavior happens.

**THIS IS THE PROBLEM**
When I go back to the original view, the button appears, but then never disappears. It is almost like the `removeFromSuperView` is not being called, but even if it is, the button is not removed.

Any ideas why this is?

```
-(void)autoRotationDetection
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
     name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
     object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
}

- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    UIDevice * device = note.object;
    switch(device.orientation)
    {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            /* start special animation */
            [_menuButton removeFromSuperview];
            break;

        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            /* start special animation */
            break;

        default:
            break;
    };
}
```

Then I call

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [self autoRotationDetection];
}
```

Sorry should have added that.

Comment: You should show the method where you're calling removeFromSuperview.

Comment: I added the code:-) Sorry I forgot:-)

Comment: 1. Verify your method is getting called, 2. Verify that `_menuButton` is not `nil` and points at the correct menu button. 3. Make sure you're in the main thread (I think it should be).

Comment: Make sure you remove the observer in `viewWillDisappear`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this kind of behavior (behaving differently after going to another tab and coming back again) when a call to [super viewWillAppear] is left out. Try adding that, and see if it fixes it.

**After Edit:**

I think an easier way to do this is to just look at the bounds of the view in viewWillLayoutSubviews, which is called every time there's a rotation (and other times as well, but for a simple thing like this, that shouldn't matter). In this example I'm hiding or showing rather than removing, but the concept should work for both.

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    BOOL portrait = self.view.bounds.size.height > self.view.bounds.size.width;
    if (portrait) {
        self.button.hidden = YES;
    }else{
        self.button.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

You could make this more efficient by keeping track of the value of portrait the last time this method was called, and only change the button's status if the portrait has changed.

Comment: I may putting in the wrong place, but it is giving me an error:-)
I have put it in the viewWillAppear Method

Comment: So, the code you show in your question is not what you actually have in viewWillAppear?

Comment: @JeffKranenburg Make sure you added `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` and not just `[super viewWillAppear]`.

Comment: Done exactly as you said and still have the same issue. and yes the viewWillAppear was exactly as I had posted it.

Comment: @JeffKranenburg, I edited my post to show what I think is a simpler method.

Comment: Ok I tried that and it is still stuck, I will scan my code again and see if I can pin point it down more. Maybe I have not implemented the button properly.

Comment: @JeffKranenburg, yeah, I've tested this, and it works fine for me, so there must be another issue.

Comment: After copy and pasting all my code, I found out that I had a method in my viewWillAppear instead of my viewDidLoad, so it was initializing the button each time the view loaded, but of course only removing it once - hence it looked like it was "sticking"